# Referencing javascript from trac wiki

Tags: javascript, trac

I have a problem running javascripts from trac. 
I know there are security issues around this, but my trac installation is only used as an intranet.

I have got the following code to work (requires setting rendering_unsafe_content = true under [wiki] in trac.ini):

```
{{{
#!html

<script type="text/javascript" >
document.write("This is a test")

</script>

}}}
```

However, replacing this with the javascript in a seperate file will fail:

```
{{{
#!html

<script type="text/javascript" src="/tracproject/htdocs/test.js" >

</script>


}}}
```

where tracproject is the root folder of trac and test.js contains document.write("This is a test").

Any clues?

Comment: Are you 100% sure `/tracproject/htdocs/test.js` exists? Can you verify e.g. using Firebug whether the script file actually gets loaded? What does the final generated HTML look like?

Comment: I think you are on the right track, Pekka. I tried Firebug and when I inspected the code after the <script type="text/javascript" src="/tracproject/htdocs/test.js" > I got the following:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
2<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
3
4
5
6
7 <head>
8 <title>
9 Error: Not Found – ModemTech
10 </title>
11 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />....

Comment: The line 9 Error: Not found - Modem Tech probably means that the script never was loaded? I haven't used this debugger before so I'm not too familiar with its features. Does this observation give any new clues?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 'Add Headers Plugin' (http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AddHeadersPlugin) ?  It looks like it allows you to do include custom javascript like you want but in a more straightforward way than having to modify templates directly.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The option is `[wiki] render_unsafe_content` (see [documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracIni#wiki-section)). You can reference the file in your site htdocs directory on the path `/tracproject/chrome/site/test.js`. I tried your example just now and it work correctly once the `src` path is changed.

See the [TracInterfaceCustomization](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization) page for more details.